Proguard-obfuscated stack traces incorrect in Firebase Crashlytics, even after uploading mapping file
I have an Android app built with Android Studio using Gradle, and it uses Proguard for obfuscation. After uploading the .aab file to the Play Store, I noticed that the crashes reported in Firebase Crashlytics are incorrect. Here's an example of a stack trace:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to read from field 'boolean d3.z0.D0' on a null object reference
com.cbm.qmobile.ui.main.LinechartFragment.isOnViewCreatedCalled (LinechartFragment.java:23)
com.cbm.qmobile.ui.main.ChildFragment.setNoDataText (ChildFragment.java:23)
com.cbm.qmobile.ui.main.ChildFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$4 (ChildFragment.java:475)

The problem:

Line mismatch: In the LinechartFragment, line 23 is an import
statement, so this line number in the stack trace is clearly
incorrect.
Obfuscated symbols: 'boolean d3.z0.D0'? I
understand this is due to obfuscation, but the stack trace is not
being de-obfuscated properly, even after uploading the mapping file.

Here’s what I’ve done so far to try to resolve the issue:

Added mappingFileUploadEnabled true to my app-level build.gradle file:
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        firebaseCrashlytics {
            mappingFileUploadEnabled true
        }
    }
}

This didn’t make any difference.

Manually uploaded the mapping.txt file to the Play Console at:
C:\Users\Makram\AndroidStudioProjects\QMobile\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt
After doing this, it seems that the "Crashes and ANRs" section in the Play Console is now empty, which is puzzling.


Also I do know that I can simply add the follwing lines to the proguard-rules.pro file:
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

However, I want to avoid this because:

It increases the app's file size.
It reduces security, and the mapping file should be sufficient for de-obfuscation.

